# Replacement Problem in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a replacement problem in VB.NET: I need to replace the " character:

```
result = result.Replace(""", "")
```

How can I make this work? Is is even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a VB literal string, use "" to mean " - So

```
result = result.Replace("""", "")
```

Note the four `"` chars in a row - begin string, two consecutive that mean a single set, and the end of string.

Comment: So would `result = result.Replace("\""","""")` work if I were trying to replace `\"` with `"`?

Answer (score 4):

I dont know VB.NET but try

```
result = result.Replace("""", "")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
result = result.Replace("""", "")
```

VB uses `""` to provide a `"` character in a string without exiting the quotes.
Most other languages use an [escape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Programming_and_data_formats), such as `\"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for the VB char constant `"`

```
""""c
```

To fix your sample, use the following

```
result = result.Replace("""", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape it

```
result = result.Replace("""", "")
```